# Installing Exchange on a different server after failed primary server

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I'm trying to get my exchange server back online, however, after rebuilding my SBS server, exchange install keeps failing. I used the following steps to rebuild my server.

Prior to reinstalling SBS 2008:

- Copied live IS from failed server
- Removed Exchange data from metadatabase with ADSIedit
- Seized roles from failed SBS server with ntdsutil

Steps to reinstall SBS 2008

- Installed SBS 2008 in migration mode with old server name and IP
- Exchange install failed during setup
- Tried removing Exchange and reinstalling manually

Now I cannot remove management tools and anytime I run setup from a command line, all I get is "Exchange Server encountered an error."

Comment: I suspect you've missed some Exchange info in ADSI.  :(

Comment: It was actually a problem in a registry key. The install path was missing a \ on the end. Now I have other issues mounting the store dbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error when running setup was due to the install path for Exchange server missing the trailing `\`

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the live transaction logs as well? The Information Store may not be able to cleanly mount the database without performing some level of log replay. Run eseutil against the copied store db, it will tell you if it is in a clean or dirty shutdown state.